# Rcpp can't dyn.load library: Missing __si_class_type_info

Tags: c++, r, compilation, fortran, rcpp

I am trying to compile an R package that contains both C++ and Fortran code using Rcpp. The compilation works perfectly fine, but the package can't `dyn.load` the shared object, throwing the error:

`undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE`

Applying a `c++filt` to this gives:

`vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info`

The package is the `sf_onefolder` branch from here: https://github.com/blowfish711/PEcAnRTM.

I thought this might be because of some compatibility (or lack thereof) with the latest R version, but an older R version on a different system gives the same error.

I don't necessarily even need an answer to this as much as a way to debug it. I've used `gdb` with R scripts in the past, but I'm at a loss about how to approach this. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I should add that if anyone wants to replicate this error by downloading the package, the Fortran module files have to be compiled separately __before__ the main package. The `Makefile` in the `src/mk` directory will do the trick, if you copy it into the `src` directory. This is an obvious, glaring issue with the package right now, but I'm not quite savvy enough with R's Makevars yet to make it work properly, and I'm only using this package (which I developed myself) for my own purposes.

Answer (score 2):

What you post is not a *minimally reproducible example* but the first thing that comes to mind is different headers / signatures and eg the need to use 
`extern "C"` before C++ functions called from C.

You may need to something similar. It is hard to say more but there are of course package uses C++ and Fortran together.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response, Dirk! I know it's not an ideal question, but I was hoping somebody would give me a place to start looking...as you did, so thanks! I'll poke around CRAN for an R package that integrates C and Fortran.

I am unsure why the `extern "C"` should be necessary though. I'm not actually calling any C code in this package--only C++ functions, which are designed along the lines of typical Rcpp requirements. Unless I need them to wrap my Fortran calls?

Comment: Good plan. Had one come to mind I would have mentioned it. Also, the inline package recently got extended Fortran(90/95) support so you could start by simple three-liners in both Fortran and C++ -- if you only call either from R.   If you want to call C++ from Fortran or vice versa standard language tutorials should apply.

Comment: That made me think: Can Fortran arrays be converted directly to Rcpp NumericMatrix / NumericVector types? Or do I have to use basic C arrays? I feel like that could be part of the issue.

Comment: I have no idea but we use _a lot_ of C++ magic to make it transparent and easy in Rcpp.  Methinks you may have gotten ahead of yourself and need to back to "Writing R Extensions" basics for the Fortran side.  No Free Lunch, as they say...

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues when trying to call Fortran code using the Rcpp interface. I solved them by building an R package (see here [1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iv41dfcktafxh1/ABCcs_1.0.tar.gz?dl=0) for the source). Hope this helps.